# How can I get my Fancybox to work on Bigcommerce?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, bigcommerce

I previously setup Fancybox on my Bigcommerce store so that my videos would popup in a fancybox lightbox. It worked perfectly and since then I haven't made any changes to the pages, but now they are no longer working. Instead, the videos are taking me directly to youtube where the video is located. I'm including my code that I currently am using. I'm not sure why, but bigcommerce changes my code slightly on the links. It didn't cause problems before, but maybe this is where the issue is at.

This is the script I have saved as fancybox in the scripts section of bigcommerce:

```
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".fancybox").on("click", function(){
        $.fancybox({
          href: this.href,
          type: $(this).data("type")
        }); // fancybox
        return false   
    }); // on
}); // ready
</script>
```

Next, I added the fancybox in through the WebDav content and linked the necessary files in the base.html file.

This is one of the webpages I have the fancybox on:

```
<div id="floating-boxprinthelp">
<div id="floating-boxprint">
<h3 style="text-align: center;"><strong>Full Bleed</strong></h3>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-dhnujyc7at/product_images/uploaded_images/pmd-collage-full-bleed.png" alt="Precious Memories Full Bleed Print Option" width="550" height="276" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Full Bleed design covers the micro-perfed pages from edge to edge.</p>
</div>
<div class="floating-boxprint">
<h3 style="text-align: center;"><strong>White Border</strong></h3>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-dhnujyc7at/product_images/uploaded_images/pmd-collage-white-border.png" alt="Precious Memories Designer White Border Print Option" width="550" height="276" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">An alternative to the original Precious Memories Designer. Final prints feature a clean white border on all edges. <em>There are no extra perfed strips to tear off.</em></p>
</div>
<div class="floating-boxprint">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Full Bleed Bookmarks</h4>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-dhnujyc7at/product_images/uploaded_images/pmd-fb-bkmk.png" alt="Precious Memories Full Bleed Bookmarks" width="240" height="240" /></p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/ez93LB4Bv5s" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer Full Bleed Bookmark Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-Full-Bleed-Bookmarks.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<div class="floating-boxprint">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">White Border Bookmarks</h4>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-dhnujyc7at/product_images/uploaded_images/pmd-wb-bkmk.png" alt="Precious Memories White Border Bookmarks" width="240" height="240" /></p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/BeGhaHoVVcc" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer White Border Bookmark Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-White-Border-Bookmarks.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<div class="floating-boxprint">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Full Bleed Church Bulletins</h4>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-dhnujyc7at/product_images/uploaded_images/pmd-fb-cb.png" alt="Precious Memories Designer Full Bleed Church Bulletins Print Help" width="240" height="240" /></p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/50F2hmScR_I" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer Full Bleed Church Bulletin Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-Full-Bleed-Church-Bulletins.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<div class="floating-boxprint">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">White Border Church Bulletins</h4>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-dhnujyc7at/product_images/uploaded_images/pmd-wb-cb.png" alt="Precious Memories Designer White Border Church Bulletins Print Help" width="240" height="240" /></p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/9oFz4AoInn0" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer White Border Church Bulletin Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-White-Border-Church-Bulletins.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<div id="floating-boxprint3">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Directory Signs</h4>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-dhnujyc7at/product_images/uploaded_images/pmd-dsigns.png" alt="PMD Directory Signs" width="240" height="240" /></p>
</div>
<div id="floating-boxprint2">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Full Sheet</h4>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/lgwT8Bh8K4o" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer Directory Sign Full Sheet Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-Directory-Sign-Full-Sheet.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<div class="floating-boxprint2">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Half Sheet</h4>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/i_R9Dy3jO2M" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer Directory Sign Half Sheet Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-Directory-Sign-Half-Sheet.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<div class="floating-boxprint2">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Lectern</h4>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/pL5UKtsOcgM" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer Directory Sign Lectern Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-Directory-Sign-Lectern.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<div id="floating-boxprint3">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Grave Markers</h4>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-dhnujyc7at/product_images/uploaded_images/pmd-gm.png" alt="PMD Grave Markers" width="240" height="240" /></p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/xirSYv6SgCI" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer Grave Marker Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-Grave-Markers.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<div class="floating-boxprint3">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Memorial Candles</h4>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-dhnujyc7at/product_images/uploaded_images/pmd-candles-lady.png" alt="PMD Memorial Candles" width="240" height="240" /></p>
</div>
<div id="floating-boxprint2">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Square Candles</h4>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/Mm4S-Vc5LVU" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer Square Candles Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-Square-Candles.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<div class="floating-boxprint2">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Small Candles</h4>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/Qz807ghiz30" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer Small Candles Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-Small-Candles.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<div class="floating-boxprint2">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Large Candles</h4>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/lIFi0v6dckk" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer Large Candles Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-Large-Candles.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<div id="floating-boxprint3">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Picture Frames</h4>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-dhnujyc7at/product_images/uploaded_images/pmd-picture-frame.png" alt="PMD Picture Frames" width="240" height="240" /></p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/kKxCYO2CNOE" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer Picture Frames Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-Picture-Frames.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<div id="floating-boxprint">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Full Bleed Prayer Cards</h4>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-dhnujyc7at/product_images/uploaded_images/pmd-fb-pc.png" alt="PMD Prayer Cards Full Bleed" width="240" height="240" /></p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/aB7gmtg5nF8" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer Full Bleed Prayer Card Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-Full-Bleed-Prayer-Cards.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<div class="floating-boxprint">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">White Border Prayer Cards</h4>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-dhnujyc7at/product_images/uploaded_images/pmd-wb-pc.png" alt="PMD White Border Prayer Cards" width="240" height="240" /></p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/3T_6Cqj-WOs" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer White Border Bookmark Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-White-Border-Prayer-Cards.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<div class="floating-boxprint">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Full Bleed Register Books</h4>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-dhnujyc7at/product_images/uploaded_images/pmd-fb-rb.png" alt="PMD Full Bleed Register Books" width="240" height="240" /></p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/PWIBXl641Ng" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer Full Bleed Register Book Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-Full-Bleed-Register-Books.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<div class="floating-boxprint">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">White Border Register Books</h4>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-dhnujyc7at/product_images/uploaded_images/pmd-wb-rb.png" alt="PMD White Border Register Book" width="240" height="240" /></p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/A0iz8Gvvb2w" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer White Border Register Book Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-White-Border-Register-Books.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<div class="floating-boxprint">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Full Bleed Service Records</h4>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-dhnujyc7at/product_images/uploaded_images/pmd-fb-sr.png" alt="PMD Service Records Full Bleed" width="240" height="240" /></p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/woCLwY7QfdU" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer Full Bleed Service Records Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-Full-Bleed-Service-Records.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<div class="floating-boxprint">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">White Border Service Records</h4>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-dhnujyc7at/product_images/uploaded_images/pmd-wb-sr.png" alt="PMD White Border Service Records" width="240" height="240" /></p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/4zsCVTqbd14" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer White Border Service Records Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-White-Border-Service-Records.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<div class="floating-boxprint">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Full Bleed Thank You Cards</h4>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-dhnujyc7at/product_images/uploaded_images/pmd-fb-tyc.png" alt="PMD Full Bleed Thank You Cards" width="240" height="240" /></p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/iIwg0CfjFbk" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer Full Bleed Thank You Cards Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-Full-Bleed-Thank-You-Cards.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<div class="floating-boxprint">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">White Border Thank You Cards</h4>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-dhnujyc7at/product_images/uploaded_images/pmd-wb-tyc.png" alt="PMD White Border Thank You Cards" width="240" height="240" /></p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/qgEPWTTrZd8" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer White Border Thank You Cards Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-White-Border-Thank-You-Cards.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<div class="floating-boxprint">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Full Bleed Trifolds</h4>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-dhnujyc7at/product_images/uploaded_images/pmd-fb-trifold.png" alt="PMD Full Bleed Trifolds" width="240" height="240" /></p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/GvyZAYwQU4E" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer Full Bleed Trifold Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-Full-Bleed-Trifolds.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<div class="floating-boxprint">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">White Border Trifolds</h4>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-dhnujyc7at/product_images/uploaded_images/pmd-wb-trifold.png" alt="PMD White Border Trifolds" width="240" height="240" /></p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://youtu.be/Hm1DNGQaY8w" data-fancybox="">Video</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Precious Memories Designer White Border Trifolds Print Help" href="https://bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/pdf/PMD-White-Border-Trifolds.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">PDF</a></div>
</div>
<video id="myVideo" width="640" height="320" style="display:none;" controls="controls"><source src="https://youtu.be/ez93LB4Bv5s" type="video" /><source src="https://youtu.be/BeGhaHoVVcc" type="video" /><source src="https://youtu.be/50F2hmScR_I" type="video" /><source src="https://youtu.be/9oFz4AoInn0" type="video" /><source src="https://youtu.be/lgwT8Bh8K4o" type="video" /><source src="https://youtu.be/lgwT8Bh8K4o" type="video" /><source src="https://youtu.be/pL5UKtsOcgM" type="video" /><source src="https://youtu.be/xirSYv6SgCI" type="video" /><source src="https://youtu.be/Mm4S-Vc5LVU" type="video" /><source src="https://youtu.be/Qz807ghiz30" type="video" /><source src="https://youtu.be/lIFi0v6dckk" type="video" /><source src="https://youtu.be/kKxCYO2CNOE" type="video" /><source src="https://youtu.be/aB7gmtg5nF8" type="video" /><source src="https://youtu.be/3T_6Cqj-WOs" type="video" /><source src="https://youtu.be/PWIBXl641Ng" type="video" /><source src="https://youtu.be/A0iz8Gvvb2w" type="video" /><source src="https://youtu.be/woCLwY7QfdU" type="video" /><source src="https://youtu.be/4zsCVTqbd14" type="video" /><source src="https://youtu.be/iIwg0CfjFbkE" type="video" /><source src="https://youtu.be/qgEPWTTrZd8" type="video" /><source src="https://youtu.be/GvyZAYwQU4E" type="video" /><source src="https://youtu.be/Hm1DNGQaY8w" type="video" /> Your browser doesn't         support HTML5 video tag. </video></div>
```

Comment: You did not mention fancybox version you are using, there are API differences between major versions. JS code seems to be from v2, but `data-fancybox` attributes are from v3.

Comment: Janis, I used whatever files were provided on the Fancy Box site. I added it in just a couple of months ago so it should be the newest version.

Comment: If you are using v3, then your js code will throw error. So, remove it or update according to docs https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#usage see sample https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/VGoRqO?editors=1010

Comment: Hi Janis, it does not seem to throw any errors it just no longer works. Here is the code I have in the base.html page for fancybox: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://www.bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/fancybox/src/jquery.fancybox.min.css" /> and  <script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://www.bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/fancybox/src/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
          <script type ="text/javascript" src="http://www.bass-mollett-publishers.mybigcommerce.com/content/fancybox/src/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

Comment: Can you give me an example using the actual code from my store. It's confusing trying to change it to fit bigcommerce?

Comment: It definitely doesn't matter what is on the page or how it is generated, html/css/js works the same everywhere. It should work fine if you have successfully included all files and there is no JS error on you page (any JS error can prevent further execution of the code; hit F12 and check console tab for any message). Here is a demo with your html code - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ROWOMQ?editors=1000

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at this Janis. I realized the problem was that I had switched my site over to HTTPS and my scripts were trying to run through HTTP. After I looked through the errors I was able to see this. Thank you for suggesting it.